# In gdb, if I use strcmp() for conditional breakpoint. I am not able to use colon ':' in string parameter.print

Tags: gdb

Suppose I want to put breakpoint in gdb like this:

```
break file.cc:x if strcmp(my_string, "A:B")
```

In above breakpoint statement, 'x' is line number and 'mys_string' is valid string variable.

But I get following error.

```
"" is not a function
```

If I put second string in strcmp without colon like "AB" instead of "A:B" it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your GDB if possible. 7.11 has no issue with this.

```
(gdb) break file.cc:7 if strcmp(foo, "A:B")
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40052a: file file.cc, line 7.
```

Comment: I am using "GNU gdb Fedora (6.8-37.el5)". Is there no way to use ':' with said version?

Comment: That's a really old gdb!  Anyway you could try making the breakpoint and condition separately, like `(gdb) break file.cc:77` and then `(gdb) cond 1 strcmp(my_string, "a:b")`